# How do you tell when a channel is closed _while sending_?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-coroutine-channel

The following hangs forever. I would like the suspend function to just return somehow if the send cannot complete.

```
suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    val channel = Channel<Int>()
    
    //channel.close()
    
    launch {
        println("closing")
        channel.close()
    }
    
    channel.send(0) // hangs forever!!
    println("end")
}
```

So basically what I need is a version of `SendChannel.send` that just throws or returns when the channel is closed while it's suspended.

Comment: Closing a `Channel` stops you from sending any more elements (i.e., closed for sending), but the channel remains open for receiving until the already-sent elements are all consumed. Since you don't have anything receiving from the channel, that means a call to `send` before `close` is going to block forever. So, one solution is to consume the channel somewhere. However, if you want the channel to "stop" immediately, perhaps you really want to `cancel` the channel rather than `close` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you would like the `send` function to throw or return if the send cannot complete.

You have a rendezvous channel with no buffer, so `send` will always suspend until the channel's `receive` function is called. But that doesn't mean that your `send` call can't complete.

Even though the channel is closed, `receive` can still be called to successfully deliver a value that is already "in flight". In that case, the suspended `send` call will return normally.

The channel's order of operations is the same as the order that you called its functions in. A consumer reading from the channel will first see the value `0`, and then will reach the end of the channel, because `send` was called *before* `close`.

This is mentioned explicitly in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/send.html) for the `send` function of a channel.

> Closing a channel after this function has suspended does not cause this suspended send invocation to abort, because closing a channel is conceptually like sending a special "close token" over this channel. All elements sent over the channel are delivered in first-in first-out order. The sent element will be delivered to receivers before the close token.

The `close` function is part of the `SendChannel` interface and is intended for the **sender** to indicate that it isn't going to send any more values. It doesn't drop values that have already been sent, or are already in the process of being sent.

A channel also has a `cancel` function, which is part of the `ReceiveChannel` interface. The `cancel` function is intended for the **receiver** to indicate that it doesn't want to receive any more values. This will drop all the values that have already been sent, and will cause any ongoing `send` attempts to fail with an exception.

In your example code, if you replace `channel.close()` with `channel.cancel()`, the in-flight call to `send` will fail with an exception.

Comment: You are correct and I had just come to that conclusion myself. :)

Comment: The reason I had been confused is in my full (not stripped down) codebase, I was using `consumeAsFlow` to receive elements and close (I guess cancel) the channel. I had assumed that consumeAsFlow would cancel it correctly but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer though as it answers the original question. I'll make a separate post for my consumeAsFlow problem.